# re-check in every iteration

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I want to loop through files as long as there's files left (Where I edit and remove files inside the loop but `glob.glob` seems to only initialize at the beginning of the loop and not in every iteration. How can I get this achieved?

Thanks,
Ron

**edit 1**
I tried:

```
for MyBuff in glob.glob(DATA_FOLDER+"*.bin"):
    tarcmd = TARBIN+" -cjf "+DATA_FOLDER+str(int(time.time()*100))+".tar.bz2 $(find "+DATA_FOLDER+" -name \"*.bin\"| head -500)"
    #...tarcmd operations and removal of the 500 inserted bin files
```

Now, the problem is that I tar up to 500 files into the tarball but what if there's more than 500? I want to loop until no bin files are left...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I've tried to loop using `glob.glob()`

Comment: That's everything? Just one line (respectively one argument) to achieve your aim?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I'm sorry for my brief answer to your question, I added **edit 1** above, please have a look. Thank you!

Comment: Your doing it wrong :D Are you trying to make tarballs out of 500 file chunks, or are you trying to put only 500 files into one tarball?

Comment: @JoelCornett I'm trying to pt 500 files from the file list `find` returns into the tarball. I believe that works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are text files, Here is a way but I'm not sure if this is the best one.

```
import os, re
filepath = '/path/to/file/directory/'
result = [f for f in os.listdir(filepath) if re.search(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+\.txt$', f)]
for f in result:
   print f
```

Comment: this will loop depending on how many files got indexed in result before the loop. Assuming you remove files, it won't recheck in every iteration...